# how to bind value with air date-time picker Jquery plugin with a model?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

I am using air Datetime picker Jquery plug in to show the date to the input box. The information can be found below. 
https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-Clean-Date-Picker-Plugin-with-jQuery-Air-Datepicker.html

When I bind with a model, I can't see data coming to the script. What did I do wrong?

```
<input ng-disabled="defaultSaveButtons[$index]" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" 
class="form-control text-right inputFill2 datepicker-here" data-language='en'
 ng-model="field.value" value="{{field.value}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `onSelect` and try listening on the value change when the object of date-picker is initialized as in the following example:
In your init function `initDatePicker` put this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateFormatted, date, e) {
        // affect the value to the desired scope variable
        $scope.dateValue = dateFormatted; // or date
    }
});
```

In HTML

```
<input ng-init="initDatePicker()" ng-disabled="defaultSaveButtons[$index]" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" 
class="form-control text-right inputFill2 datepicker-here" data-language='en'
 ng-model="field.value" value="{{field.value}}"/>
```